# Alternate for $size in aggregate after doing $unwind

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using aggregate to generate a pipeline.In my aggregate operation doing $lookup with another collection which results in giving 16mb BSON limit error for resulting collection. Searched about the problem found $unwind which will unwind the data into separate rows this works fine now I want to count the number of elements from the unwinded list. If its a list I would use $size on it.
Mongodb version used - 3.4

I tried doing count but it gives total count. I need results exactly like the size.

```py
db.user.aggregate([
{'$match': {'dateAdded': {'$gte': ISODate("2013-10-09T00:11:00.130Z"),
            '$lt': ISODate("2019-10-09T00:11:00.130Z")}}},
{'$lookup': {'from': 'course',
             'localField': '_id',
             'foreignField': 'userId',
             'as': 'course'}},
{'$project': {"email": 1,
             "firstName": 1,
             "lastName": 1,
             "dateAdded": 1,
             "numberOfCourse": {"$size": "$course"}}}])

# will give me result like below
[* 1 */
{
    "_id" : JUUID("d97af13f-c800-4000-b4ef"),
    "lastName" : "abc1",
    "email" : "abc1@gma.com",
    "dateAdded" : ISODate("2015-10-09T00:11:00.130Z"),
    "firstName" : "abc1",
    "numberOfCourse" : 5
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : JUUID("66ff26fd-eb04-4000-afdc"),
    "lastName" : "abc2",
    "email" : "abc2@gma.com",
    "dateAdded" : ISODate("2015-08-24T17:33:10.887Z"),
    "firstName" : "abc2",
    "numberOfCourse" : 20
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : JUUID("1b1ac31f-ec22-4000-a1df"),
    "lastName" : "abc3",
    "email" : "abc3@gma.com",
    "dateAdded" : ISODate("2016-08-08T11:37:37.533Z"),
    "firstName" : "abc3",
    "numberOfCourse" : 30
}]
```

Now if number of courses is more than 16mb for the list above approach will not work. Please suggest proper way of achieving the same result with $unwind.

Comment: I guess you're reaching out the maximum limit of a mongoDB document can you provide your sample data, that way we can look on refactoring your query..

Comment: Yes, it's reaching out maximum limit of MongoDB document which i already mentioned in the question. That's why using unwind as suggested while searching for the problem. I am new to mongo to trying to figure out how to achieve same results now.

Comment: we've many ways to count num of documents $count or even doing a $group on date and $sum would similar, So each course document has a list or one userId ? I don't think you understood when I've asking for sample docs from your two collections, if you can provide those we can check on it, it would be simple then.

Comment: say for example user collection is [{user_id: xxx1}, {user_id:xxx2}, {user_id:xxx3}] and course collection will look like [{course_id: cs1, user_id:xxx1},{course_id: cs2, user_id:xxx1}, {course_id: cs3, user_id:xxx2}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're saying you've query working and added $unwind, then try this :

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'dateAdded': {
                '$gte': ISODate("2013-10-09T00:11:00.130Z"),
                '$lt': ISODate("2019-10-09T00:11:00.130Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'course',
            'localField': '_id',
            'foreignField': 'userId',
            'as': 'course'
        }
    }, { '$unwind': '$course' },
    { '$group': { _id: '$_id', count: { $sum: 1 }, "docs": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } } }, { '$addFields': { 'docs.numberOfCourse': "$count" } },
    { '$replaceRoot': { 'newRoot': "$docs" } },
    {
        '$project': {
            "email": 1,
            "firstName": 1,
            "lastName": 1,
            "dateAdded": 1,
            "numberOfCourse": 1
        }
    }])
```

Here we're grouping by _id of user after unwind and as we already have count just adding first document in the group rather than all in-order to overcome same issue & preserve original document after group usage thru `"docs": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }` and as original doc is wrapped in *docs* used `$replaceRoot` to bring it to top-level.

Comment: mergeObjects is a problem its not available in 3.4. I am getting the counts with you solution however not getting all the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested pipeline where you will directly get count of course

Try this

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "dateAdded": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2013-10-09T00:11:00.130Z"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2019-10-09T00:11:00.130Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "course",
            "let": {
                "$userId": "$_id"
            },
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": { "$eq": ["$$userId","$userId" ] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$count": "numberOfCourse"
                }
            ],
            "as": "course"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "email": 1,
            "firstName": 1,
            "lastName": 1,
            "dateAdded": 1,
            "numberOfCourse": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$course.numberOfCourse",  0 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks but i am using mongodb 3.4.

Comment: Are you using mongoose ?  If yes try to use populate else I update mongodb to 3.6

Comment: Cant upgrade production system that easily.

Comment: If you are using mongoose then use populate https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thanks however i am not using mongoosejs